# Multiple inheritance with QObject

Tags: c++, qt, polymorphism, multiple-inheritance, qobject

I want to inherit QObject and another class and got an error:
undefined reference for `vtable for EduGraph'
I've read some threads about it and have fixed the sequence of the inherited classes in the class definition, but it haven't solved the problem.

```
class EduGraph : public QObject, public Graph<Vertex<ENode, EEdge>*> {
private:
    std::list<Vertex<ENode, EEdge>*>::iterator firstSel;
    std::list<Vertex<ENode, EEdge>*>::iterator secSel;
public:

Q_OBJECT

    EduGraph() : firstSel(0), secSel(0) {}
    ~EduGraph();

    void NewNode(const QPoint& p);
    void RemoveNode();
    void Associate();
    void Dissociate();

signals:
    void VertexSelected();
    void VertexDeSelected();
};
```

Comment: Are you sure you need multiple inheritance? From the above code, using composition looks like it would work (i.e. have a `Graph<...>` member in your class rather than inheriting from it).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Undefined reference to vtable in Qt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15656902/undefined-reference-to-vtable-in-qt)

Comment: Also, [C++ Undefined Reference to vtable and inheritance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9406580/c-undefined-reference-to-vtable-and-inheritance)

Comment: Does rerunning qmake help? Also, the Q_OBJECT macro is technically supposed to be in the private section of your class definition. Customarily, it's the first thing after the opening curly brace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
`Undefined reference to `vtable for...'`
```

is usually a sign of unimplemented virtual function.
Make sure you have implemented (defined) the corresponding **virtual functions you inherited from the base classes**.

For example this will give you the same error because the print method in B is not implemented.

```
class A {
public:
    virtual void print() = 0;
};

class B : public A{
public:
    void print();
};

int main()
{
    B b;
}
```

Comment: Your example will [not give any error](http://ideone.com/N8acL1) unless you actually call the `print` method.

Comment: It does give an error message on gcc 4.4.0 at least. **You don't get an error message if you don't declare an instance of B**. Hence why i have put a declarion in main.

Comment: First of all that is (gcc-4.7.2). Plus even if that was the same version, what you are trying to do is tell me that what I am looking at right here on my terminal is a result of my imagination. Maybe it is but I doubt it.

Comment: Instead of just saying it doesn't you can atleast try to explain why it shouldn't or if it is caused by some configuration ....

Comment: The rule says *cannot create any objects of an Abstract class*.An abstract class has atleast one pure virtual function.Without the overidding method in `B`,Your class autmotically becomes a Abstract class and compiler will complain if you [just create an instance](http://ideone.com/rtjLXQ).Once you override the method `print()`. You instruct the compiler,My class is not Abstract & promise the compiler to provide its definition whilst the linking.This is similar to declaring a method and not defining it, [no error](http://ideone.com/RwLUik) until [method invocation](http://ideone.com/uWUsp6).

Comment: You can make the base class non abstract. `virtual void print() {}`. I still get the same error. I can even add other virtual methods which I inherit and define properly. However as long as `print` is inherited but not defined the error stays.

Comment: And `undefined reference to A::print()'` and `undefined reference to vtable for B'` are not the same errors.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27239/discussion-between-ras-and-alok-save)